# Getting an error when running this stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2, and I'm receiving the following error when I run the stored procedure `sp_smc_add_personuser`.

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Here's the code that I'm trying to run.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_smc_add_personuser] 
as
--source variables
declare @personid int
declare @samid nvarchar(256)
declare @rdate datetime
declare @cdate datetime

DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @TERM VARCHAR(6)


--SELECT  @YEAR=ACADEMIC_YEAR,
--  @TERM=ACADEMIC_TERM
--FROM  SMCHELPER..CURRENTTERM
--WHERE OFFICE='ADMISSION'

declare cur_PersonAD cursor for

select distinct p.personid,ad.samid as UserName,getdate() as CreateDate, getdate() as RevisionDate from people p 
inner join smchelper.dbo.activedirectory ad on p.people_code_id=ad.empid
inner join academic a on p.people_code_id=a.people_code_id
where ad.samid in (select samid from smchelper..activedirectory)
and (a.academic_flag='Y' or a.application_flag='Y')
and a.academic_year >= '2012'
and p.personid not in (select personid from campus6.dbo.personuser)

open cur_PersonAD
fetch next from cur_PersonAD into @personid,@samid,@rdate,@cdate

while (@@fetch_status<>-1)
begin
    if (@@fetch_status<>-2)
  begin
--print @personid
--print @samid

if not exists (select personid from personuser pu
where pu.personid=@personid and
pu.username=@samid)
  begin     
    insert into personuser
        values 
        (@personid
        ,@samid
        ,@rdate
        ,@cdate
        )
    end
end
fetch next from cur_PersonAD into @personid,@samid,@rdate,@cdate
end
close cur_PersonAD
Deallocate cur_PersonAD
```

EDIT - I'm looking for some help chasing the problem down because I'm not quite sure how to go about troubleshooting this. If all you can do is give me some general strategies for troubleshooting (given that I can't use the built-in debugger due to permissions issues), then that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you need a cursor? This procedure RBAR doesn't appear necessary!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error appears to be here:

```
insert into personuser
        values 
        (@personid
        ,@samid
        ,@rdate
        ,@cdate
        )
```

You should explicitly list which four columns in `personuser` you want to populate with the supplied values

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Your syntax is only valid if `personuser` is exactly four columns.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That got me the rest of the way to resolution